# opinions on two guitar models? (epiphone vs yamaha)

Tags: semi-acoustic-guitar

Im considering two options for an electro-acoustic guitar, epiphone aj-210ce or yamaha fx310A. Could you give me any opinions/recommendations as to which model might be best?